# Why are fonts not rendered the same in a browser and a terminal?

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, fonts, unicode

To be more specific, let's suppose I have a monospaced font with some glyphs larger than the normal character width (for example, fontawesome icons).

In most terminal emulators, the larger characters will simply overlap on the character on the right, while in chromium for example, larger characters will push the rest of the line to make space for itself.

Why is that? What is rendering the text in those applications? Is it the app itself? Is it an operating system component? Are terminals specifically designed to avoid this problem?

And the complementary question : is there any way to make chromium behave like most terminals, so that monospaced fonts stay monospaced even when there are larger glyphs.

To provide some background, I'm working on [hyper](http://github.com/zeit/hyper), which is basically a terminal in chromium, and this is causing issues with characters alignment.

Comment: “What is rendering the text in those applications?” – The answer to that is unfortunately: It depends.

Comment: Looks like a really nice project! :)

Comment: "let's suppose I have a monospaced font with some glyphs larger than the normal character width" - then it's not a monospaced font ... "A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space."

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm well aware of that thanks. Still, there are many monospaced fonts that are patched with glyphs from other fonts, often icons. See https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts for example. This is useful to make pretty terminal prompts for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most apps (including browsers) obey the glyphs' dimensions as defined in the font. In fact they probably use methods that display longer strings in one step (although I'm not aware of the details). If some of the glyphs are a bit wider than the rest then it's not an entirely monospace font, it's almost monospace with some exceptions.

Terminal emulators use a special drawing method, they position each character independently because they need to force the characters into a grid, otherwise the overall layout would just fall apart. You can especially nicely see this in action if you choose a non-monospace font (the result will look ugly, but remain grid-aligned). (Note that `konsole` might be an exception, I've seen it doing weird things.)

To make browsers behave like terminal emulators, I recommend you to try placing each and every character separately in its own `span` or `div` with `position: absolute` or `fixed`, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I thought. We're already using `span`s in hyperterm to fix the beaviour, unfortunately it's hurting performance a bit.

Comment: thanks. maybe that's why my texteditor can't have same effect as terminal 

(CJK or Emoji characters can't align)

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems provide a number of text drawing facilities that the developers are able to choose from. Terminal emulators usually require mono spaced fonts and the text rendering you see is a natural result of this constraint. Browsers use more sophisticated facilities that allow proportional fonts and much more. That doesn't mean that many options will be provided to the user. The browser rendering you see would usually be preferred. Of course not everyone will agree.

Can Chromium render text as you desire? I doubt it but you can check the text options.